# Does the iif function compute both paths in SSRS or is it short-circuited?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, iif-function

I am trying to evaluate a Price per Kilo ($/Kg) based on sales of a product.  This works fine if the product was acutally sold during the period specified.  However if the product is not sold the Kg (the denominator) ends up being 0 (zero) and an error results. - Divide by Zero error.

I tried this

```
=iif(KgSold=0,0,Revenue/KgSold)
```

It appears that the `iif` function is calculating both the true and false results.  How do I get around this.

Should I be using the `switch` function instead?

```
=switch(KgSold=0,0
        KgSold<>0,Revenue/KgSold)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're right, it doesn't short circuit.  That sucks.

You'll have to do something like this:

```
= Iif(KgSold = 0, 0, Revenue) / Iif(KgSold = 0, 1, KgSold )
```

The switch function should also work.

Comment: Thanks Robert. That does work.  I am still getting the divide by zero error so now its just a matter of hunting the error down.

Comment: I found the where the error was happening.  it was in the SQL and not in the report.

Comment: Tried the switch function for my dilemma and it also seems to evaluate all statements.

Comment: @UserSmith: Then use the other variant I posted here.

Comment: Mine was a lot more complicated than the above.  Although I found this solution....... works pretty well.  =REPLACE(Fields!MYFIELD_CONCAT.Value & "  ", ",  ", "")

Answer (score 6):

This happens because in VBScript all conditions within an IIF will be evaluated first before any functionality occurs.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  I figured that was the case.  I suspect that it is the case for all flavours of VB.

Comment: Note: full up VB.NET now has an IF() ternary operator that does short-circuit; but as implied, SSRS is using the VB Script or "VB for Applications" subset, and does not have that.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your code:

```
Public Function SafeDiv(byval num as double, byval den as double) as object

    If den = nothing then return nothing
    If den = 0 then return nothing

    return num / den

End Function
```

Then call

```
=Code.SafeDiv(Revenue,KgSold)
```

in the text box epression