# SSRS error: Conversion from string "string;#NA" to type 'Date' is not valid

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

My datasource is XML (sharepoint list). I basically want to show the date formatted if the value in the field is a date and if not then show "NA". For some reason, even when the data is a a string it is still trying to convert it to a date somewhere. Here is my code..

```
=IIF
(
ISDATE(replace(First(Fields!ows_Manufacturing_Date.Value, "DataSet1"),"datetime;#","")),
formatdatetime(replace(First(Fields!ows_Manufacturing_Date.Value, "DataSet1"),"datetime;#",""),2),
replace(First(Fields!ows_Manufacturing_Date.Value, "DataSet1"),"string;#","")
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the IIF statement in SSRS doesn't short circuit, it always evaluates both conditions, so even if the field is not a date, it still tries to do the formatdatetime function.

(See this: [SSRS iif function question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204179/does-the-iif-function-compute-both-paths-in-ssrs-or-is-it-short-circuited))

Instead of the `IIF` function, try using the `SWITCH` function instead:

```
=SWITCH(First(Fields!ows_Manufacturing_Date.Value, "DataSet1")="string;#NA",
"NA",
First(Fields!ows_Manufacturing_Date.Value, "DataSet1")<>"string;#NA",
formatdatetime(replace(First(Fields!ows_Manufacturing_Date.Value, "DataSet1"),"datetime;#",""),2))
```

Comment: took me 3 hours try to understand why the formatDateTime still executes when if condition if false until I find your post