# NaN SSRS Expression Fix

Tags: reporting-services

I'm working on a SSRS report and I keep getting a `NaN` value when I'm doing a divide here. How can I replace the `NaN` with 0 in my statement?

```
=Fields!Whse_QTY.Value/Fields!Total_QTY_Sales.Value
```

Comment: Also see the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432714/divide-by-zero-null-workaround-in-ssrs-2008-report/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful due to the lack of short circuiting in the `IIf` statement.

Something like:

```
=IIf(Fields!Total_QTY_Sales.Value = 0, 0, Fields!Whse_QTY.Value)
  / IIf(Fields!Total_QTY_Sales.Value = 0, 1, Fields!Total_QTY_Sales.Value)
```

should do the job.