# How to calculate ratio in SSRS if some values can be string "-"

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

Instead of showing $0 I'm showing "-", which is string value. 
But then I need to calculate "Overall % of WP", which is 'WrittenPremium'/"Total Written Premium"  and if there is no $ amount it will take string "-", and because of that I got an error. 
How can i fix it? How can I say in my expression something like, if you see "-", then dont divide, just 0.

[image]

I am trying something like that:

```
=IIF(ReportItems!TotalWrittenPremium.Value<>0, ReportItems!Written_Premium.Value/(ReportItems!TotalWrittenPremium.Value ),0)
```

But still giving me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's generally not a good practice to refer to report items like `ReportItems!Written_Premium.Value`. Here's what I would suggest:

1. Add a calculated field to your dataset that removes the dashes. Let's call it "Calculated_Premium" for this example. The expression would be:

   =CDec(IIf(Fields!Written_Premium.Value = '-', 0, Fields!Written_Premium.Value))
2. Refer to this new column in your table like this:

   Written Premium

   `=Fields!Calculated_Premium.Value`

   Total Written Premium

   `=Sum(Fields!Calculated_Premium.Value)`

   Percent of Total

   `=Switch(Sum(Fields!Calculated_Premium.Value) = 0, 0
       , True, Fields!Calculated_Premium.Value / Sum(Fields!Calculated_Premium.Value))`

Answer (score 0):

This **might** be the issue with **IIF** trying to resolve both parts of the equation leading to a **DIV0** error.

```
=IIF(ReportItems!TotalWrittenPremium.Value <> 0, 
        ReportItems!Written_Premium.Value /
        IIF(ReportItems!TotalWrittenPremium.Value = 0, 1, ReportItems!TotalWrittenPremium.Value)
    , 0)
```

If you run it in Visual Studio, you might get a better error message in the **Error List**.

[Does the iif function compute both paths in SSRS or is it short-circuited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204179/does-the-iif-function-compute-both-paths-in-ssrs-or-is-it-short-circuited)

[divide by zero/null workaround in SSRS 2008 report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432714/divide-by-zero-null-workaround-in-ssrs-2008-report?rq=1)

Comment: Still giving me the same error.  I think the problem is because I have string value "-"