# Why case statement fails while comparing data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have stored **OpeningDate** as a varchar(100) and **OpeningTime** as Time in the table.

I have tried everything but this throws an error:

**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CAST(OpeningDate AS DATE),106), --Cast to DATE first to get the style needed
       CASE WHEN 
            (   CAST(OpeningDate AS DATETIME)+ -- Cast to DATETIME
                CAST(OpeningTime AS DATETIME)  -- Also here
            ) < GETDATE() 
             THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 END AS OpeningVaild
FROM Works;
```

Comment: what is  the datatype of OpeningTime

Comment: TIME............

Comment: Your query works for me

Comment: RegBes' answer is a good hint and you might read my comment below Chanukya's answer about culture dependant date/time formats... Always try to save your data in a column with the appropriate format. Using a string-format for a date value is slowing down your queries and is erronous - as you've found out...

Comment: It's a case _expression_ not a statement

Answer (score 2):

Now one answer has got deleted - and with it my comment...

There are several issues:

- `CONVERT`-style 106 is meaning `dd mon yyyy`. Is this your needed **output** format?
- If you cast a value like `2018-04-02` to `DATETIME` this is culture dependant.
- It is a bad idea to store a date-value in a string-typed column. This will slow down your queries and is erronous...

Try this out:

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT CAST('2018-04-02' AS DATETIME)

SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT CAST('2018-04-02' AS DATETIME)
```

Is it the second of April or the fourth of February?

Now try the same with a cast to `DATE`...

This is a bit quirky and weird, but it's legacy... Use the new formats `DATE`, `TIME` and `DATETIME2` to avoid this.

Another sure approach is the ISO8601-format. This is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`. You can cast a string like `2018-04-02T12:32:45` to `DATETIME` in any culture.

And of course there is the chance for invalid strings like `2017-02-29` (no 29th of Feburary in 2017!) or any kind of crap-data in your string-column...

You can search for crap-data with `ISDATE` (see RegBes'answer) [or you might try `TRY_CAST()` (needs v2012+)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

One more option is to simulate `TRY_CAST` with XML methods (since v2005):

```sql
DECLARE @SomeDates TABLE(d VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @SomeDates VALUES('2018-04-02'),('2017-02-29'),('crap data')

SELECT TRY_CAST(d AS DATE)      --needs v2012 
      ,TRY_CONVERT(DATE,d,102)  --needs v2012 and allows to specify the mask (102: yyyy.mm.dd)
      ,(SELECT d FOR XML PATH('x'),TYPE)
       .value('(/x/d/text())[1] cast as xs:date?','datetime')
FROM @SomeDates;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that some of the data in your OpeningDate field may not be a valid date format.

run this to get all the records that may have issues

```
select *
from works
where isdate(OpeningDate) = 0
```

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736733/error-in-ssrs-expression-for-false-condition/52739800#52739800