# Convert Crystal Reports formula to SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services

```
IF {Field_A} = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (({Field_B} / {Field_A})*100)
```

I am trying to convert this formula to an SSRS expression. I have tried many different `=IFF` statements, but cannot seem to get it to run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Almost a duplicate question: if you search here for `#error ssrs iif` you'll get plenty of results, such as [Does the iif function compute both paths in SSRS or is it short-circuited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204179/does-the-iif-function-compute-both-paths-in-ssrs-or-is-it-short-circuited)

Rewriting you statement is straightforward then:

```
=IIF(
   Fields!Field_A.Value = 0,
   0,
   Fields!Field_B.Value /
   IIF( Fields!Field_A.Value = 0, 1, Fields!Field_A.Value) * 100 )
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have several formulas to convert, it is OK to do manually. However when you have quite a few complicated formulas to convert from Crystal to SSRS, you need a conversion tool to help. Please try Crystal Migration Services. Formulas like this canc be perfectly automatically converted. Free sample conversion is also available for you to evaluate.

http://www.crystalmigrater.com/Default.aspx