# Convert Crystal Report formula to SSRS Expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217610/convert-crystal-reports-formula-to-ssrs-expression) question, but it was asked too earlier.

I'm trying to covert crystal report formula to `ssrs-expression`. What could be the ssrs-expression for below example?

**For example:**

```
if(instr({?@Code},",") > 0) then
   formula = "My Text"
elseif(len({?@Code})>0) then
   formula = "FOR XYZ " + {?@Code}
end if
```

I need to convert it into `ssrs-expression`

**Note:** *This is just an example I'm having so many complex formulas like above.*

Also, is there any blog - site - link where can I find all the formulas conversion code for ssrs-expression?

Answer (score 1):

You will need something like this

```
=iif(instr(Parameters!Code.Value, ",") > 0; 
    "My Text", 
    iif(len(Parameters!Code.Value)>0), 
        "FOR XYZ " + Parameters!Code.Value, 
        ""
    )
)
```

Please also see the [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx#VisualBasicFunctions) for example expressions

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's correct but is there any site where we can convert all crystal report formulas to ssrs expression?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but then I've never needed it. If you can't find one with google, then probably not

Comment: good answer! `If you can't find one with google, then probably not` :-D