# SSRS value display #error for ssrs conditional expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2

This is the expression used for calculating the value:

```
=iif((Sum(CDbl(Fields!RxCount.Value))=0),"0.00",(Sum(Fields!Margin.Value)/Sum(CDec(Fields!RxCount.Value))))
```

ie:

> if Sum(CDbl(Fields!RxCount.Value = 0, result shoul be 0.00 otherwise
>   it should be the divide of two values.

but it display `#error` when `Sum(CDbl(Fields!RxCount.Value = 0` not `0.00`

Any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the iif function compute both paths in SSRS or is it short-circuited?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204179/does-the-iif-function-compute-both-paths-in-ssrs-or-is-it-short-circuited)

Comment: There are a number of duplicates of this question. Search on `SSRS iif #error` to find many answers pointing at a couple of different workarounds.

Comment: Maybe field Fields!RxCount.Value doesn't return integer/decimal value or value that can be converted to integer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test for null values as well, the #Error is likely occurring because

```
Sum(CDbl(Fields!RxCount.Value))
```

is returning a null value, not a 0.

Comment: hi kyzen, I use cdec also it display same "#error" result

Comment: Try this:  

* Add the RXCount field to a table.
* Set a filter on the table to filter out any rows where Fields!RxCount.Value is not null (you can use IsNothing()).
* Run the report, look to see how many rows are coming back with nulls.

You may be able to just slap an Isnull(RxCount, 0) into your source query if the difference between null (no value) and 0 (a value of 0) don't matter.