# Does the SSRS Switch function Evaluate the results of all conditions, as the IIF function does?

Tags: vba, reporting-services

Many are aware that the `IIF` function does not "short circuit". [Does the iif function compute both paths in SSRS or is it short-circuited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204179/does-the-iif-function-compute-both-paths-in-ssrs-or-is-it-short-circuited)

So, does the `Switch` function also *not* short circuit? In other words suppose we have this `Switch`:

`Switch(True, 5, False, 5/0)` a contrived example of course.

Will it cause an error because it will evaluate 5/0?

Comment: I hate to be the one to ask this, but.... **have you tried it?**

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ - I did, admittedly with a more complex `Switch`. And to my amazement it looked like it *did* evaluate all the results - like the `IIF` does. But I haven't tested such a straight forward example as this. When I have time I will, and probably post an answer if no one else has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Switch` **doesn't** short circuit. It shows the same behavior as `iif` evaluates all conditions.

But the expression `Switch(True, 5, False, 5/0)` won't show an `#error`.

It will evaluate fine. It will show 5. As 5/0 will evaluate in SSRS as `infinity` not `#error`.

A better test will be

```
=SWITCH(TRUE,5,FALSE,5/"")
```

When using the above expression, SSRS will evaluate it to `#error` instead of 5.

Comment: i find myself returning to read this question/answer because I just can't accept that SSRS has all this hasltle