# IIF construct not resolving the correct way (SSRS)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've got a problem with this piece of code inside a parameter in SSRS2012.

```
=IIF(InStr(Parameters!P1.Value,"@")=0,
"missing @", 
Left(Parameters!P1.Value(InStr(Parameters!P1.Value,"@")-1)))
```

My aim is to check if the parameter P1 contains a "@" if it doesn't i will print "missing @" otherwise i want to remove from that parameter what's after the "@" ("@" inculded).

example:
P1 = 123456 --> print "missing @"
P1 = 123@56 --> print 123

The problem is that SSRS drops the error: "Argument 'length' must be greater or equal to zero" when i insert a value with no "@". (when i insert a value with an "@" it goes all well)

It seems like the IIF resolves the 2 expressions first (rather than one is true or false) and after that it gives you the correct one based on the evaluation of the first condition.

Looking for some help. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the iif function compute both paths in SSRS or is it short-circuited?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204179/does-the-iif-function-compute-both-paths-in-ssrs-or-is-it-short-circuited)

Comment: not a duplicate, tried the switch function and it's the same

Comment: Could it be that the parameter only contains the '@' symbol and nothing else?

Comment: not really, for example this parameter --> 123@56 generates the error too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a weird bug, here is one solution

```
=replace(replace(IIF(InStr(Fields!P1.Value,"@")<> 0,
left(Fields!P1.Value,InStr(Fields!P1.Value,"@")),"missing"),"@",""),"missing","missing @")
```